# wxPython Crashing randomly at THIThemeTextInfoPublic::GetOptions() const + 9

Tags: python, macos, wxpython

I'm writing an application for a uni project, and after about 5 minutes it just crashes.

I'm on a MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard, with python 2.6, and wxPython 2.8.12, and according to the crash log i am using `libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib`, I'm not a C or a C++ programmer and it is infuriating me. The copy of the crash log is avaliable at http://pastebin.ca/2063975

Comment: — How did you install wxPython? Did you download one of the OS X disk images from http://www.wxpython.org/download.php? If so, which one.

Comment: I downloaded `wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-py2.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the crash log, it appears that you are using OS X's system python. I believe this defaults to 64-bit, which isn't compatible with wxPython based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923651/error-importing-wxpython/5924906#5924906), this [blog post](http://blog.widenhome.com/2011/02/02/setting-up-wxpython-dev-environment-on-mac/), and from the [wxPython download website](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php#stable), which states:

> Since they use the Carbon API they are limited to running in 32-bit mode.

I'd recommend installing `python-2.6.6-macosx10.3.dmg` from [python.org](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/).

Comment: Thanks, also forcing python to run in 32-bit mode helped.
Setting `VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes` changed python to 32-bit(for anyone interested)